# How does onLocationChanged works?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

in my application i have a button that start counting the time how long the user has been in the same location. and i want the app stop the timer counting if the user goes out from the area he started so i made a class that give me the current location (LAT,LONG,PLACE NAME) and i don't know how to use the "onLocationChanged" and Should I use it? or something else for what i need?

```
public class MapCurrentPlace extends Service implements LocationListener {


    private final Context mContext;

    public static final String MY_TEMP = "sharedFile"; 

    SharedPreferences setting;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    String placeName = "";


    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 500; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;



    public MapCurrentPlace(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();

    }



    public String getPlaceName(){

            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(mContext);
        try {
                List<Address>  list = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                 if(list.size()>0){
                String city = list.get(0).getLocality();
                String street = list.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                placeName = city+", "+street+"";        
    }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            placeName = "";         
            e.printStackTrace();
            }



        return placeName;
    }


    public Location getLocation() {

        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                      // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);








            if (!isGPSEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled

                 this.canGetLocation = false;
                return null;

            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,0, this);

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }

                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,0, this);

                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return location;
    }


    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(MapCurrentPlace.this);
        }     
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public boolean getIsNetworkEnabled() {

        return this.isNetworkEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS OFF");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Allow GPS");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("SETTING", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation
```

this one returns last know location fix. This might be kind of old if no apps requested location for a while. 
Location updates will be fired each time device location was changed.

So it's up to you what to use. If you want to get up-to date location, use location updates. But bear in mind that location updated drain battery.

Also you might want to look into Geofences: http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: I guess it drain battery .. There is no more cost-effective way to perform this action?

Comment: When you require location updates, then preferred way is to use Google Play Services. I believe most optimisations are already there. Only option for you is to decide what kind of location updates are necessary for you in terms of accuracy and time.

Answer (score 0):

The onLocationChanged method will be called when the current location is changed. This is a default method called because you have implemented the LocationListener. 
I do not know how you are implementing the timer (perhaps an AsyncTask so your app can do other stuff as well - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), but then in the OnLocationChanged method add some call to your timer variable to stop.

Answer (score 0):

`OnLocationChanged` will trigger whenever the device travels the `minDistance` parameter of [`requestLocationUpdates`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), from the last relevant location of your device (i.e. since the event last triggered).

Of course, the trigger rate also takes into account the minTime parameter, which should be used to prevent saturation of the calls, and thus saving battery/data usage (e.g. car travelling too fast for your minDistance).

As you have it now (you supplied an inline 0 to the call), you need to **manually check** if the most recent `OnLocationChanged` data is a relevant change to your scenario.

It's much more transparent to just use that parameter as the system tries to make it hardware-independent and battery-efficient. You already have a *MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES* in your boilerplate code, just add it as a parameter instead of '0' as you have, and set it to the number of meters you need:

```
// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 30; //30 meters

//...
    //at some point while your service/activity is running
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                                    this);

//...

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLocation) {
    //triggered when System asserts a 30 meter variation from last relevant location
    doMyStuff();
}
```

*Side note: remember most GPS hardware has issues with very fine locations, especially at sub-10m.*

You can also keep the value at 0, receive updates at the granularity the hardware updates itself, and do the checks manually - just use the `Location` parameter supplied with the event and do your own checks to decide, which is pretty much a geo-fencing check:

```
Location lastRelevantLocation;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLocation) {
    // called when the listener is notified with a location update from the GPS
    // hardware update rate might call this more than your CPU should handle

    if(checkOutsidePerimeter(location)){
        lastRelevantLocation = currentLocation;

        doMyStuff();
    }
}
```

Remember minTime if you want to keep tabs on granularity.